# HH:MM Format in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I m using a stored procedure and there i m having a column Name timespent which i want to show like HH:MM format only, the procedure is working fine but the only problem is that currently the time spent is coming as hh:mm:ss format. Guide me how i ll get time spent in HH:MM format and correct my procedure if possible.
The procedure is like that:-

```
CREATE procedure St_Proc_GetUserReportforCurrentDayTask              
@userID int              
as              
Begin              
    set NoCount on;              
    DECLARE @TODAY DATE                
    SET @TODAY = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 111)              
    select CONVERT(VARCHAR,production.CalendarDate,101) + RIGHT (CONVERT(VARCHAR,production.CalendarDate , 100 ) ,7) as Date,               
    RegionAndProjectInfo.RegionProjectName as Region ,              
    County.CountyName as County,              
    WorkType.WorkTypeName as WorkType,              
    Task.TaskName as Task,  
    Production.VolumeProcessed as 'Volumes Processed',              
    Production.TimeSpent as 'Duration (HH:MM)'              
    from Production               
    inner join RegionAndProjectInfo              
    on              
    RegionAndProjectInfo.RegionProjectID=Production.RegionProjectID              
    inner join County              
    on               
    County.CountyID=Production.CountyID              
    inner join WorkType              
    on              
    WorkType.WorkTypeID=Production.WorkTypeID              
    inner join Task              
    on              
    Task.TaskID=Production.TaskID              
    where Production.UserID=@userID and CalendarDate >= @TODAY              
End
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this

```
select SUBSTRING( convert(varchar, getdate(),108),1,5)
```

Replace getdate() with your column name.

Comment: [Please don't use `varchar` without length](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx). And wouldn't `CONVERT(CHAR(5), GETDATE(), 108)` be much simpler?

Answer (score 5):

I tried this and it worked

```
declare @dt datetime
    set @dt = '07:30'
    select convert(varchar(5),@dt,108)
```

Comment: Just a nit but doesn't really need to be `varchar` does it? It's never going to return anything but 5 characters...

Comment: @Aaron- Hi, you are right, good comment!+1