# Return HH:mm in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, time

I got a date and time inside my table. I wonder if there is a way to return the date, count of date, and time. I manage to get the **date** and the **count of date** with following query.

```
SELECT
date as dateRow,
COUNT(date) as dateCount
FROM DBName..tblName
GROUP BY date
```

The value of **time** inside my table is `HH:mm:ss` but I wanted to return only `HH:mm`.

**Sample expectation result**

> **dateRow**  | **dateCount** | **timeRow**
>   2016-11-10      11           11:35 
>   2016-11-11       3            11:40

If I add `CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),getdate(),108) AS timeRow` It returned value as expected result **BUT** the query is for capturing the current time. I wanted to display time from my table.

**EDIT :**

I had **TWO** different **SEPARATED** column for `date` and `time` inside my table. **date** column with `date` datatype. **time** column with `time` datatype.

**MY QUESTION IS :** how do I return the value of **date**, **count of date**, and **time** in SQL?

Comment: Just replace the getdate() with your column name?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HH:MM Format in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11167903/hhmm-format-in-sql-server)

Comment: Use `LEFT(timeRow,5)`

Comment: Is column type `DATETIME`?

Comment: @ChristopherTrevor I replaced the getdate() with my column name but I got error `'time' is not a recognized built-in function name.`

Comment: @NEER column type of my **time** is time

Comment: What SQL version are you using? The other easier option is to use the Format keyword:

FORMAT(date,'HH:mm') as dTime

Comment: @jelliaes I already refer to the topic but I just can't get the result with the solution they provide. TQ

Comment: did you try this? `select SUBSTRING( convert(varchar, getdate(),108),1,5)`

Comment: @jelliaes yes I did but still returning the current time. I want to return the time stored inside my table.

Comment: because you have to change the getdate() with your column name, select SUBSTRING( convert(varchar, date,108),1,5). Check my answer below for the complete query

Comment: @jelliaes got error **Error converting data type date to varchar.**

Comment: what is the datatype of your column `date`? I've tried it here it works fine. Enclose date with square brackets since date is a reserved word.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127772/discussion-between-jelliaes-and-emerald).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get TIME out of current System Time.
Use query below,

```
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT (TIME, SYSDATETIME()),5);
```

If TIME column is already present in your table the use query below.

```
SELECT LEFT(TIMECOLUMN,5);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Working great! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try it out (Assume `@TIMESPAN` as your `Time` Datatype column )

*Working for me*

```
    DECLARE @TIMESPAN TIME='12:56:23.9530000'
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),CAST(@TIMESPAN AS DATETIME),108)
```

The result will be in HH:MM

```
12:56
```

One more simple way is(with formal CAST function

`SELECT CAST(CAST(@TIMESPAN AS smalldatetime) AS TIME)`)

Result:

```
12:56:00.0000000
```

Comment: This working if I assign value to the `DECLARE @TIMESPAN TIME='12:56:23.9530000'` . How am I going to return the time stored in my table?

Comment: Just replace the TIMESPAN with your actual Table's column. I used TIMESPAN variable to test myself. @Emerald

Comment: So the query should be `CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),CAST(date AS DATETIME),108)` but it returned my time as `00:00`

Comment: Is the Date column of your table consist of data like '2016-11-10 ' or  '11:30:05' ???  And is the Date Column datatype is Time or not?? You won't get time from '2016-11-10'  unless you store time in it @Emerald

Comment: Sorry I think there is misunderstood with my question. I already improve it and I hope you get what I mean. Please check it.

Comment: From your Edit: You have column named Time with time datatype. So exactly you need to pass Time datatype column in place of DATESPAN variable. `CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),CAST([time] AS DATETIME),108)` @Emerald

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your SQL version you can use the FORMAT command:

```
FORMAT(cast(date as datetime),'HH:mm') as dTime
```

Comment: I am using SQL server 2012

Comment: The FORMAT keyword is available from 2012 onwards so the above solution would work

Comment: I tried the query and it returned `HH:mm` as `00:00`

Comment: What is the actual value of the data in the database?

Comment: Time consist of different value such as `11:35:01` , `11:35:02` , `11:35:03` , `11:36:10` , `11:36:11` and I want to return only `HH:mm` such as `11:35` , `11:36` at every rows

Comment: I updated my answer, just tested it and when working with time columns you need to cast them to datetime before using format or they will always return null

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you've changed your datatype to datetime:

```
SELECT
date as dateRow,
COUNT(date) as dateCount,
SUBSTRING(convert(varchar, date,108),1,5) as timeRow
FROM DBName..tblName
GROUP BY date, SUBSTRING(convert(varchar, date,108),1,5)
```

OR try this if you'll not change your datatype to datetime

```
SELECT
DateOfLoan as dateRow,
COUNT(date) as dateCount,
SUBSTRING(Convert(varchar, convert(datetime, date), 108),1,5) as timeRow,
convert(datetime, date)
FROM loan
GROUP BY date, SUBSTRING(Convert(varchar, convert(datetime, date), 108),1,5)
```

but this will return 00:00 since you're datatype is date

Comment: Still get the same **Error converting data type date to varchar**

Comment: what is the datatype of your column `date`? I've tried it here and it works fine. Enclose date with square brackets since date is a reserved word.

Comment: I use `date` datatype for my **date**.

Comment: if your datatype is date, then there will be no time for your column timeRow. Try changing your datatype to datetime, so when you're saving, you may also save the hour and seconds.

Comment: I've updated my answer. But I suggest you change your datatype to datetime if you really want to get the hh:mm

Comment: Actually I separated my date and time in the table, that's why my date column is date datatype and time column is time datatype. I tried to return value from column date and column time. Refer back my question above.

Comment: Ohh. I think your question is misleading. Can you edit your question and give us the tables affected.

Comment: what is the datatype of your column for time ?

Comment: I did mention in my question datatype for my **time** column is `time`